# Is it Possible Webmatrix CRUD in Same Page Using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, razor, webmatrix, single-page-application

I would like to get idea about, what is the fastest and secure way to make CRUD operations (Update-Edit-insert) in samepage with Ajax in WebMatrix Razor Syntax.  Is it possible to do this CRUD Operations in same razor page with ajax without GET-POST webservice or other razor page?

I tried using jquery ajax to Post-Get data from other Razor pages with Output type Json and also using WCF Webservice. But they didnt really satisfy me, because in all i need another page to serve my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Each separate CRUD operation would have to be wrapped in its own conditional block. The condition can test to see if a particular name/value pair has been sent to the server via AJAX (e.g. `action=delete` or `action=update`). When returning values back to  AJAX call, make sure that the `ContentType` of the Response is set correctly.

Here's a working example -

```
@{
    if(IsAjax){
        switch(Request["action"]){
            case "create" :
                Response.Write("You are trying to create something");
                Response.End();
                break;
            case "read" :
                Response.Write("What would you like to read?");
                Response.End();
                break;
            case "update" :
                Response.Write("Something is being updated");
                Response.End();
                break;
            case "delete" :
                Response.Write("This is a delete");
                Response.End();
                break;
        }
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('.crud').click(function () {
                    $.get('/SinglePage/?action=' + $(this).attr('id'), function (message) {
                        alert(message);
                    })
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="create" class="crud">Create</button>
        <button id="read" class="crud">Read</button>
        <button id="update" class="crud">Update</button>
        <button id="delete" class="crud">Delete</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anything, this illustrates how bad this approach might be in terms of maintenance etc. I would always use separate cshtml files for each data operation myself,

Comment: can the page, post itself using ajax with handling these Crud operations or, data has to be returned from other page.

Comment: All the CRUD operations would be in the same page. You do not need to have separate pages. The pages would not "post to itself". The AJAX calls would be to the same URL and your server-side code would identify which operation is required and execute the code accordingly. I have update my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks, you saved my day, there is not much in depth detail available on internet about webmatrix razor.